# MainActivity.this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxmlfile) nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android

in the MainActivity class, why am i getting a nullpointerexception for the commented line

```
private Context context;
public MainActivity(Context con) {
    super();
    this.context = con;
}
private InputStream is;
public MainActivity() { 
    /// NPE HERE
    this.is= MainActivity.this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.allstops);
}
public InputStream getIs() {
    return is;
}
```

P.S: I did this after onCreate() method only. allstops is an xml file in res/raw folder.

Comment: Why are you using `MainActivity.this`?

Comment: With this many sub-calls, you could print each to see which is null. `System.out.println(context);` then `System.out.println(context.getResources());` then `System.out.println(R);`, then `System.out.println(R.raw);`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor (where you set `this.is`) is done BEFORE `this.context` is set. `context` is going to be `null` causing your `NullPointerException`. You need to move the `this.is` line to after the `this.context` assignment.

Comment: moving this.is line after this.context is causing class instantiation exception.(no empty constructor). Also, I need to pass the file to another class ReadXMLFile which parses the xml file. how do i do both

Comment: Remove the empty constructor and call the other class to parse the XML file.